# Error reading time cell in Excel using SQL (VBA)

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have an excel worksheet with 7 tables (each placed in a different sheet) and I built a routine to select through them, consolidating the data in a single sheet.

All tables have an HOUR column and I have two types of select: a full time range, where I select every row in each table, and a part-time range, where I select only the data between 6:00:00 and 23:00:00.

```
For i = 2 To Sheets.Count
   ...
   strSQL = "SELECT [APPLICATIONNAME], [DAT], [TRANSACTION_NAME], SUM([TOT]), AVG([PERFORM]), SUM([ERRO]), AVG([TOTAL_TIME]), AVG([PERCENTUAL_AJUSTADO]), [HOUR], LEFT([HORA],2) " & _
            "  FROM [" & Sheets(ind).Name & "$] " & _
            " WHERE (LEFT([HOUR],2) >= 6 AND LEFT([HOUR],2) <= 23)" & _
            " GROUP BY [APPLICATIONNAME], [DAT], [HOUR], [TRANSACTION_NAME]" & _
            " ORDER BY [DAT], [HOUR], [TRANSACTION_NAME]"
   ...
Next i
```

The problem is that it works fine only when I read the first three tables. From the fourth table on, it seems that Excel is converting the time cell to a numeric value and the data becomes incomplete.

I believe it's not a problem of cell formatting, because if I change the order of the sheets, the SELECT continues reading the first three tables perfectly.

I made it print the time read and the LEFT([hour],2). The results for the first three are, for example:
hour = 22:00:00
LEFT([hour],2) = 22
From the fourth table on, the results are (always):
hour = 8,3333333333333
LEFT([hour],2) = 8,

What may be happening?  Is there another way to make it work for all sheets?

Thanks in advance.

Ricardo Freire

Comment: Is `Ind` declared? Specify `Option Explicit` at the top of the module - if the code doesn't compile, fix it by declaring the undeclared variables... or replacing their usages with variables that *are* declared.

Comment: Yes, every variable is declared, I always use "Option Explicit" in my code.  The index is correct in the code (I changed the for variable, but I forgot to change it in the SQL statement in the question).